# mongoose updateOne query not updating

Tags: node.js, mongodb, typescript, mongoose

I have used `updateOne` plenty of times, but this one particular call is not working.

I have tried using the `ObjectId`, but i can still GET my user object with this string userId.

But if i do use `ObjectId`, I get this type error when using it as a filter value for `_id`

```sh
2322: Type 'ObjectId' is not assignable to type 'Condition<string>'.  Type 'ObjectId' has no properties in common with type 'QuerySelector<string | RegExp>'.
```

this is my existing, very simple code.

```js
// i do set the key like this
const key = "profile.name";

const result = await UserModel.updateOne({
    _id: userId
}, {
    $set: {
        [key]: "new name"
    }
}, {
    overwrite: true // looked online that this may help, but this still doesn't do anything
});

console.log(result);
// { n: 1, nModified: 1, ok: 1 }
```

this doesnt update my user:

```js
> db.users.find().pretty();
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("6053b530e9f654250a747b26"),
    "profile" : {
        "_id" : ObjectId("6053b530e9f654250a747b27"),
        "name": "old name" // <<<< this should be "new name"
    },
}
```

also - Though the record does not update in the database, this model's `updatedAt` time changes! But the field is not changing.

anyone have any ideas? I am banging my head on this desk. I cannot figure this out

EDIT: This could be a bug in mongoose, see this issue: https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/issues/10045

Comment: Dd you ever solve your issue?

Comment: @JoelPeltonen I could not fix on that version of mongoose, I had to upgrade my mongoose version. See the github thread: https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/issues/10984